# In a-frame vr my raycaster intersects with entities that have visible="false" property set

Tags: aframe

If I use laser-controls and the raycaster="objects: [widget]", my raycaster still emits events when intersecting [widget] selectors with visible set to false.

I expect the raycaster to register intersections with "shouldintersect" by NOT "shouldnotintersect"... by default this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

setting raycaster to: raycaster="objects: [widget]:not([visible=false]); lineColor: #fff; lineOpacity: 0.7; far: .1"

using :not([visible=false]) will hide the object from the raycaster.